# Confusion Matrix Matlab has a 0% for a class during training

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

When I train Multi-Layered Perceptron using Matlab for 6 classes, for one of the classes I get a 0% in GREEN in the confusion matrix. This leads to to a high error percent for the overall training, validation and testing. What is the cause for this and how may I resolve this problem ?

The training data has little more than 200 instances per class. There are a total of 1225 instances.

Target file is created as follows:
If there are 2 characters say A and B in the input then for each row in input matrix for character A there is a corresponding row in Target with 0,1 and for every character B there is a 1,0 row in target. So the input nodes in the NN will be 900 and output nodes will be 2 for this example.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals here? I'm not sure this question is answerable in its present form. Eg, what is "MLP"? What is your total N, & how many cases do you have in each class? Etc.

Comment: I have now uploaded the image of my confusion matrix that I obtain after training my MultiLayered Perceptron (MLP) Neural Network !

Comment: I am trying to train the Neural Network for handwriting recognition. Currently for only 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What is your total N, & how many cases do you have in each class?

Comment: There are approximately 200 instances for each class. There are 900 input nodes and 6 output nodes. I have tried to train with a single hidden layer of 10 nodes, 20, 30, 100, 200, 600 nodes. But the error varies only slightly.

Comment: What do you mean by Total N ?

Comment: "Total N" means how much data you have in total--ie, how many patterns. If you have 6 classes w/ 200 instances each, N=1200. Often the phenomenon you describe comes when 1 class has very few instances. You should add the info above into your question. Maybe someone will know what the problem is.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll add the details to the question

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reduce the dimensions of the input layer by using a different feature vector. This helped. When the input layer has a large number of neurons then the Neural Network requires a larger number of instances to train and find the best combinations of weights. When I reduce the number of neurons in the input layer then the number the weights that needs to be updated decreases too thus the NN converges.